# iOS8 crash while redirecting to ABPersonViewController as [Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, addressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

```
ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
personController.personViewDelegate = self;
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(personController.addressBook, [recordID intValue]);
personController.displayedPerson = person;
personController.allowsEditing = YES;
personController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back",nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(returnFromPersonView)] ;
personController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:personController];
navController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:27/255.0 green:27/255.0 blue:29/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[self presentViewController:navController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Getting crash in  this line personController.displayedPerson = person; as 
[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: use instruments and enable the zombies tool! that way you can see what object is messaged after a dealloc call and who are the releases

Answer (score 1):

Try to get addressBook not from controller, but explicitly create it instead:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &err);
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, [recordID intValue]);
```

Comment: I don't see how creating an address book will help here -- the person is returned retained (Get) in the name. -- still worth a try :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan I'm not really sure why, but this works. It gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the first (original) case, and works with this one. Probably this is because at this stage `addressBook` property is not properly created. From the doc: [_When unset, an address book is created and assigned to this property when needed._](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ABPersonViewController/addressBook), so it is not clear when it actually will be created.